# Подружить поле для загрузки файлов с кодом php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, вот часть кода php, считывает данные с загруженного файла,

```
if (isset($_POST["Import"])) {
echo $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if (!$_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {}
```

Работает с этой формой

```
<form method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="input-large">
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="Import" >Upload</button>
</form>
```

Помогите переделать под это поле, и без кнопки отправки

```
<input type="file" name="jform[params][file]" id="jform_params_file" />
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю какой результат нужен?

Answer (score 1):

php

```
if (isset($_POST["Import"])) {
echo $filename = $_FILES["jform"]["tmp_name"]["params"]["file"];
if (!$_FILES["jform"]["size"]["params"]["file"] > 0) {
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {}
```

html

```
<form method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="jform[params][file]" id="jform_params_file" class="input-large" />
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="Import" >Upload</button>
</form>
```